# Getting Stripe to work with Commerce

Tags: plugin-craftcommerce, ecommerce, omnipay-stripe

We're using Stripe for an ecomm project that we're testing out right now and nothing is hitting Stripe. If we use a bad card number ([per Stripe's docs](https://stripe.com/docs/testing#cards)) like 4000000000000002, the order still goes through.

The Stripe account is brand new (hasn't fully been activated yet) and in Test mode and the test secret and publishable keys are in Commerce's settings. I'm not sure what else to check.

EDIT:

I had forgotten stripe.js altogether but now I'm getting "Payment information submitted is invalid." which I think is a Craft/Commerce error. [Here's a link](http://d.pr/f/Ogol) to my checkout template code. The wrapper template (extended template) contains [this javascript](http://d.pr/f/kj4y) before the closing body tag.

Comment: Are you sure you're looking in the right stripe account? Also are you using the test api keys from your stripe CP, and not the production keys? Also, are you using stripe.js or checkout.js on the front end?

Comment: Just tested this on a shop I'm developing right now. That card gives me a "Your card was declined." error.

Comment: @LukeHolder - yes, correct Stripe account, test API keys from Stripe CP. I may be missing the JS. Have to look again.

Comment: Alright, so I was missing stripe.js. Added all that per Stripe docs and now just get "Payment information submitted is invalid" which is a Craft/Commerce error from what I can tell. I've edited my original question to reflect this and added links to code.

Comment: Where is your [``stripeResponseHandler``](https://stripe.com/docs/custom-form#step-3-sending-the-form-to-your-server) in your JS?  So basically your code is hitting Stripe with the card details to get the token. So you have the token, now your JS needs to insert that token back into the form so Commerce on the server side can actually submit the form and do what it needs to do with the token.

Comment: Angie, before trying to implement stripe.js which is the more advanced method. Have you tested the checkout.js stripe example included in the supplied example templates?

Comment: Oof, what a noob move! Thanks @RitterKnight - that was the last missing piece.

Comment: @AngieHerrera Could you add that as an official answer for the next person to run into this issue?

Comment: @BradBell Oh I suppose I could do that. ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Issue was not RTFM. :) Basically I didn't include [every part of the stripe.js setup](https://stripe.com/docs/custom-form)